# Replace string using Regex.Replace

Tags: c#

i have a string

```
string findText = "Paid part-time job (under 8 hours per week)";
```

i want to replace this string with some other string (`replaceText = "Paid for job"`) using `Regex.Replace()` as follows :

```
Regex r = new Regex(findText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
findText = r.Replace(findText, replaceText);
```

but the problem is that this string is not getting replaced, may be due to presence of braces in the text.

Can anyone suggest how this whole string can be replaced using `Regex.Replace()`?

Comment: So you want to replace "part-time" with "for"?

Comment: No i want to replace the whole string with "Paid for Job" or any other string. what i want is that i should be able to replace the whole string even if it contains special characters. Due to special characters , it is not getting replaced using regexOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need *at all* for the usage of regular expressions here.
Simply use [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

```
var result = original.Replace(findText, replaceText);
```

Comment: actually i need to use regular expressions here bcoz i have to consider the case sensitivity case here.

Answer (score 0):

For your example it is easier to use String Replace:

```
string result = yourString.Replace(findText, replaceText);
```

But if you still want to use regex, you should escape braces, for example this way:

```
string findText = "Paid part-time job [(]under 8 hours per week[)]";
```

and call it **pattern** instead of findText :)

Comment: actually this findText is coming from some database, so cannot escape the braces...